# Running bash loop in parallel across multiple nodes on a cluster

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

On an individual node I have been able to run the precompiled function update_OSS_internal_compiler in parallel (16 cores) with different inputs specified by $FileCounter. However, I would like to extend this parallel processing to beyond one node to multiple nodes, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

```
#!/bin/bash

. /u/local/Modules/default/init/modules.sh
module load matlab
export MCR_CACHE_ROOT=$TMPDIR

Macro_Iter=10
ApertNum=121

FullPath=$(pwd)
TempFileFolder=$FullPath/TempFiles

for MacroLoop in $(seq 1 1 $Macro_Iter); do
# WANT TO SSH INTO DIFFERENT NODES AND RUN SAME PROCESS WITH DIFFERENT INPUTS WHILE UPDATING FILECOUNTER AFTER EACH NODE, OR DO SOMETHING SIMILAR
   for FileCounter in $(seq 1 1 $ApertNum); do echo $FileCounter; done | xargs -I{} --max-procs 16 bash -c '
        {
        echo "doing aperture {}"
        ./update_OSS_internal_compiler {}
        } '
      done
   done

   echo "$FullPath/TempFiles/ApertFiles"
   ./update_OSS_global_compiler
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: One idea would be to use the hostnames `hostnames=cat $PE_HOSTFILE|awk '{print $1}'` to ssh into individual nodes, and run processes in background, then ssh into another node to do the same, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you are reinventing GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -S worker1 -S worker2 ./update_OSS_internal_compiler ::: arg1 arg2 arg3
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to. It can often replace a `for` loop.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

If GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel